# Memory leak happening while using registerModule/unregisterModule in vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex

We are observing memory leak of Store._vm while using registerModule/unregisterModule of **vuex v3.1.0**

On heap profiling we found that the oldVm instance is not getting garbage collected. [Github link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKrdy.png)

I have created an demo link to illustrate the above mentioned problem
[jsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/mrj8spu0/)

#### Steps to reproduce

1. Open the JSFiddle link mentioned as part of this issue.
2. Check and record the heap memory in the browser on initial stage.
3. Click on the "Register" button to dynamically register Module B 100 times
4. Now we will see an increase in heap memory on account of registering module 100 times.
5. Click on "Un-Register" button to dynamically un-register Module B 100 times
6. Check the heap memory again, at this point will see an jump in memory usage on account of un-registering 100 module.

**Probable Solution:**

De-reference the oldVm instance on the same function scope where its getting instantiated (i.e. resetStoreVM() )

The above can be achieved by adding following code inside resetStoreVM function.

```
function resetStoreVM (store, state, hot) {
var oldVm = store._vm;

...
...

if (oldVm) {
  if (hot) {
    // dispatch changes in all subscribed watchers
    // to force getter re-evaluation for hot reloading.
    store._withCommit(function () {
      oldVm._data.$$state = null;
    });
  }

  // Existing Code
  Vue.nextTick(function () { return oldVm.$destroy(); });

  // The OldVm Object is still in heap even after destroy
  // Appropriate Code
  oldVm.$destroy(); 
  oldVm = null;
}
```

Attached google chrome (V 72.0.3626.96) heap snapshot for your reference.
[image]